# Enable Stepped lines in Chart.Js

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I am trying to enable stepped lines in ChartJs 2.6.0

```
var chartJsObj = {
        data: {
            labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
            datasets: [{
                label: "My First dataset",
                data: [2, 23, 15, 16, 24, 21, 17, 13],
                borderColor: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
                fill: false,
                steppedLine: true
            }],
        },

    }
```

But it draws a normal curved line. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chart.js 3.x, `steppedLine` property [was changed](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/v3-migration.html#specific-changes) to `stepped`.

[Sample](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/next/samples/line/stepped.html):

```js
const data = {
    labels: ['Day 1', 'Day 2', 'Day 3', 'Day 4', 'Day 5', 'Day 6'],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: 'Dataset',
            data: Utils.numbers({count: 6, min: -100, max: 100}),
            borderColor: Utils.CHART_COLORS.red,
            fill: false,

            // Change the stepped mode to explore different stepped chart options
            // false: no stepping
            // true: stepped before interpolation
            // 'before': step before interpolation
            // 'after': step after interpolation
            // 'middle': step middle interpolation
            stepped: true
        }
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the examples of Chartjs on Github, multiple stepped line chart examples included - https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/samples/charts/line/stepped.html

The example from there recreated on Codepen - https://codepen.io/Inlesco/pen/yXEvOz

The configs for `steppedLine` on each chart in the Codepen example are defined in small chunks such as:

```
{
    steppedLine: true,
    label: 'No Step Interpolation',
    color: window.chartColors.red
}
```